# How to find maximum number of intersectionS through set of line segments

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose I am given number of lines segments in Cartesian  coordinate system.Each line is given as [x0,y0] and [x1,y1].Algorithm should find a perpendicular that cross maximum number of lines.
In this example it crosses four lines:

[image]

What algorithm can do it with minimum complexity?(i would prefer c++ but some kind of pseudo code is OK too)

P.S The point to think about is when several lines start/end in the same x coordinate

Thank you.

Comment: the algorithm question is essentially off-topic here IMO, and you haven't showed the slightest effort in starting to answer this yourself. that's not how this site works.

Comment: Even the fifth line intersects the perpendicular line, if extended. In short, every line intersects every other line if not parallel.

Comment: If they're lines the perpendicular will cross all of them, unless the lines themselves are vertical.  If we're talking about line *segments*, on the other hand ...

Comment: @Mahesh No that not what question about the lines segments are closed and cannot be extended

Comment: Yes John you right I have fixed the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Convert each line to a interval of [x_start,x_end] for each segment.
2. Create a datastructure that contains a flag for whether it is a start or end point, as well as the point value.
3. Sort all the points and then iterate through them incrementing a counter when you hit a start point and decrementing a counter when you hit an end point. Keep track of the maximum value.
4. Repeat with the Y values if desired.

O(n lg n) time complexity

Comment: Beat me to it by a minute.  I was going to suggest the same thing.  You're right, the y values are completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Similar to what I had thought of but better.  +1

Comment: what about if two lines start/end at the same x?

Comment: @zaya - Good point. It depends on how you want to handle it.  One way would be to sort the list by point and then by start/end. That way you would hit the starts first to get the overlap if that was indeed the maximum place.

Comment: Only works if the solution line is along the Y axis. He doesn't state that as a requirement but it is pictured that way.

Comment: @Jay - See (4).  I assume from the problem that it only includes lines that are perpendicular to the axes ( not 100% clear from the OP's post)

Answer (score 1):

If you want perpendicular, then here `y` aren't needed. The algorithm is following.

1. Sort lines to x0 be lower-equal to x1
2. put all points to seperate array in sorted orden and with point store a flag which tells if the point is start or end of line
3. Run on array and get the segment which belong in maximal number of given intervals

   ```
   vector<pair<double, unsigned char> > points; // (point, flag) pairs
   //read [x0, x1]s to points, be sure that x0 <= x1 (swap them otherwise)
   //0 for x0, 1 for x1
   sort(points.begin(), points.end());
   int ans = 0;
   int curstate = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
   {
       if(points[i].second == 0)
           ++curstate;
       else
           --curstate;
       ans = max(ans, curstate);
   }
   ```

Comment: what about if two lines start/end at the same x?

Comment: @zaya Yes you are right. In that case it is better to store not bool flag but integer(char) (say 0 for x0, and 1 for x1), and automaticali in your array at first will go <x0, 0> then <x1, 1>, so the answer will be correct. Now fixed to keep variable of  type `char` as flag.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of the existing lines. Build a list for each iteration containing all the other lines that are not [perpendicular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) to the current line. Sort the lists into descending order by size. The (first) list with the largest size will be the solution. It will contain a list of lines that are crossed. There are an infinite number of lines that would be solutions. Send some of your salary to me as a royalty ;)