# Find the maximum number of lines intersecting

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given n number of lines (x1,x2) ,  where x1 is start point and x2 is end point of line which are parallel to x axis. We need to draw a line perpendicular to X axis so that it intersect maximum number of lines(parallel to X axis) . How to find the coordinates of intersecting line & maximum number of intersection.

Could anyone provide some hints of solving this problem ?

Comment: If all of them are lines, so any line perpendicular to X axis will intersect with all those lines.

Comment: I cannot think of an algorithm which will help solve the problem in every case.  Consider the extreme case where all lines are very short (approaching points), and evenly spaced apart.  How could an algorithm help to find the answer?

Comment: @PhamTrung The lines don't necessarily cover the full length of the x-axis, or else the problem would be trivial and pointless.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, this problem will only make sense if they are `segments`, not lines, and If they are segments, we can use Sweep line algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037114/how-to-find-maximum-number-of-intersections-through-set-of-line-segments)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. The lines parallel to x axis coordinates will be given as input (x1,x2) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the lines are streches (limited length - i hope thats the correct term), any line that is perpedicular to the X-axis will meet the requirements. Assuming they are streches:

```
define line: int x_l , int x_r //representation of a line (y-coordinates aren't necessary)

define mostLinesX:
    input: list coords
    output: xOpt

    Map<Integer , Integer> growthMap

    for line l in coords
        put(growthMap , l.x_l , 1)
        put(growthMap , l.x_r , -1)

    int maxX = -1
    int max = 0
    int curCt = 0
    for int i in sorted(growthMap.keys)
        curCt += get(growthMap , i)

        if curCt > max
            maxX = i
            max = curCt

     return maxX
```

The basic idea is pretty simple: define a function `f(x)` that shows the number of lines that will be intersected by a vertical line at `x`. The result of this function would be the number of all lines starting before `x` minus the number of all lines ending before `x`. Now all the algorithm has to do is finding the peak of `f(x)`. `x` will always be the smallest possible value, such that no bigger `x` matching the conditions can be found.

NOTE: the end of the lines is exclusive. So if we have a line `(a , b)`, `b` itself isn't part of the line - or in other words: `(a , a + 1)` has lenght 0.